# Background color python-pptx

Tags: background-color, python-pptx

Trying to add background color to the presentation

```
   from pptx import Presentation
   from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
   from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

# Create an instance of Presentation
   presentation = Presentation()

# Define color in RGB
  blue_color = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)  # This creates a blue color
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So far you haven't done anything with the RGBColor object you've created. You have to set something's colour to this value.

Comment: Thanks. What about using it like this?

Comment: # Set the slide layout for the title slide
slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[0]
slide_1 = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

# Customize the title slide
title = slide_1.shapes.title
title.text = "Engineering Team Presentation"
title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = blue_color  # change title color

subtitle = slide_1.placeholders[1]
subtitle.text = "Introduction to the Latest Project"
subtitle.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = blue_color  # change subtitle color

Comment: That looks like it'd work. Did it?